# Bring back Tab order for the image upload dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, uploader

The image upload dialog used to have proper tab order so one could, for example on OS X, do the following:

- Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus file upload button, then <kbd>␣</kbd> (Space)
- File selection window opens; select file
- Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus upload button, then <kbd>␣</kbd> to upload

This had the benefit of not having to use the mouse at all to upload an image.

Now, when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after the dialog opens, control is still on the editor underneath the dialog. Muscle memory just made me submit the post because I tabbed to the "Post Answer" button and clicked it with Space, all while the dialog was overlaying the actual page.

[image]

I consider this a regression, as focus should be on the active dialog to make this easier accessible for keyboard-only users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with the next build we'll focus the new upload dialog, however we'll focus the "Choose file" input instead of the radio buttons.

That was the behavior of the old upload, and it makes more sense to have a quick focus on the "pick the image" part rather than the "choose where to pick the image from" since most everyone uses images from their own computer.