# Close button in image upload dialog is not tabbable and does nothing on user profile and in tag wikis

Tags: bug, user-interface, uploader

When editing a profile’s “About me” section, or a tag wiki, and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, or clicking the “Image” button from the formatting bar to insert an image, the Imgur upload modal dialog will appear.
The same modal will also appear when uploading a profile picture.
This is different from questions and answers where an uploader overlay bar (technically referred to as `inline-dialog`) appears.

This modal dialog has an <kbd>×</kbd> button for closing, but it does nothing when clicked.
I also can’t try tabbing to it and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, because it’s a regular `<div>` with no `tabindex` attribute, so it’s not tabbable and not an interactive element.
(After manually inserting a `tabindex` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it also did nothing, of course.)

[image: The close button is in the top-right corner of the modal dialog.]

There are no errors produced in the console of any browser.
It doesn’t even seem to have any event listener bound to it.

Pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key or clicking outside of the modal dialog will dismiss the dialog, but the <kbd>×</kbd> button is currently useless.

An obvious possible [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) would be to unify all Imgur upload dialogs to the way they appear on questions and answers, as an `inline-dialog`.
But for the profile picture uploader, this dialog doesn’t have an obvious alternative, so in this instance, it’s necessary to redesign the close button so that it acts as a normal button (interactive element, tabbable) and closes the modal popup.

---

### Related

- [Editor improvements for images and links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317622/289905) and [Edit your profile page still uses old image uploader](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322371/289905) — showing this modal in action; closing it *used to work*.
- [Bring back Tab order for the image upload dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169540/289905) — for an older dialog design.

Comment: If anyone is wondering, I was _not_ trying to insert an image into a tag wiki. I tried using `Ctrl`+`F` and `Ctrl`+`G` to search for specific things, but `Ctrl`+`G` brings up the image dialog…

Comment: Nomination editor has the same problem: [Image uploader close button is not responding on election nomination page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355293/289905).