# Image uploader close button is not responding on election nomination page

Tags: bug, election, uploader, nominations

In the election nomination page, the image uploader section have the old UI. The close icon on the page is not responding, so unable to close the uploader page.

**Screenshot for reference:**

> [image: election nomination - image uploader]

**Configuration:**
Operating System: Windows 10
Zoom: 100%
Mozila Firefox : 80.0.1 (64-bit)
Google Chrome : Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Clicking outside the uploader should make it disappearr, right?