# Can the editor for editing tag descriptions get updated to match the normal questions/answers editor?

Tags: feature-request, tags, editor

The text editor that is shown when editing tag descriptions still uses the previous behaviour for inserting links and images. Also, the placeholder text for links is still `http://` instead of `https://` compared to the new editor.

Another "nice to have" feature that exists in the main editor is the ability to paste an image from clipboard directly to the text editor without having to press the "insert image" toolbar-icon first.

Can it get updated to match the editor we use for questions and answers?

---

The following screenshot is an example of how it looks if I try to insert a link for a tag description:

[image: Inserting a link in the text editor of tags on Ask Ubuntu]

In comparison, this is how it looks in the new editor:

[image: Dialogue in new editor]

Comment: Related: [Close button in image upload dialog is not tabbable and does nothing on user profile and in tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353729/289905).