# Placeholder text for "Insert hyperlink" is still HTTP, when editing a tag wiki

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, tag-wiki, editor

<sup>(This might be something to do with old/new editors, but I'm not sure.)</sup>

The screenshot below:

[image]

Shows that the placeholder text for inserting a hyperlink into a tag wiki is still `http://`, and not `https://`.  As we now have network-wide `https://`, can we fix that?

Comment: Duplicate of [Can the editor for editing tag descriptions get updated to match the normal questions/answers editor?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355854/289905). A related issue is [Edit your profile page still uses old image uploader](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322371/289905); only questions and answers use the new editor, currently; tag wikis, profile pages, and election nominations still use the older version of the editor.